# BibTeX Question: 1989a,b VS 1989a, 1989b

Tags: natbib, multiple-citations

I'm loading natbib with the options authoryear, sort, comma. When I call \citet or \citep with multiple citations by the same author, in the same year, I get something like: Kaplan (1989a,b). If I use \citeyear or \citeyearpar, then I get something like: 1989a, 1989b. My publisher wants the latter. Is there a way to get this with \citet and \citep?

Comment: It doesn't depend upon the bibliography style. That controls how the bibliography is formatted, not how the citations are. It also doesn't depend upon the options with which natbib is loaded, other than authoryear of course.

Comment: Thanks to the person who posted the link to a prior answer.